# Boost Gzip chunked data decompose

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to you boost::iostreams library to decompose gziped data.
I do able to do that for simple data.

```
TEST_F(GzipTest, ZipStringChuncks)
{
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    string str_part1 { 
        char(0x1f), char(0x8b), char(0x08), char(0x00), char(0xca), char(0xb5),
        char(0x07), char(0x53), char(0x00), char(0x03), char(0xcb), char(0x48),
        char(0xcd), char(0xc9), char(0xc9), char(0x57), char(0x28), char(0xcf),
        char(0x2f), char(0xca), char(0x49), char(0xe1), char(0x02), char(0x00),
        char(0x2d), char(0x3b), char(0x08), char(0xaf), char(0x0c), char(0x00),
        char(0x00), char(0x00)
    };

    filtering_streambuf<input> decompress;
    decompress.push(gzip_decompressor());
    decompress.push(boost::iostreams::array_source(str_part1.data(), str_part1.size()));

    stringstream sstream_decompress;
    try {
        boost::iostreams::copy(decompress, sstream_decompress);
    } catch (const gzip_error &exception) {
        EXPECT_TRUE(false) << exception.what() << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "ERROR GZIP" << endl;
    }

    string unziped_str = sstream_decompress.str();
    EXPECT_EQ(unziped_str, "hello world\n");
}
```

The issue is that I need to decompress chunks of related data coming from the network. So I need to be able to decompress the first one before I get the second one. When the second one arrives as I understand it should be aware of the first one some how.

I need something like this:

```
string some_data = "...data...";
string chunks[2] = compress_in_chunks(some_data);
for(string chunk in chunks) {
    string decompressed_str = decompress(chunk); 
    cout << decompressed_str << endl;
}
```

Is there a way to do it with boost?

Couldn't find detailed documentation only few examples.

Comment: In the underlying gzip library you have to keep the same gzip stream structure instance live between calls, so I guess similarly that you need to keep the same instance returned by gzip_decompressor() between calls

Comment: I tried that, but seems like I can't 'push' more data, or it needed to be pushed in some different way

Comment: Or is it the instance of filtering_streambuf<input> decompress? And only push the decompressor the first time?

Comment: Yes, I made it a class were the filtering_streambuf<input> is a class member, and I set the gzip_decompressor() in the constructor.
Then fire message I push is fine (correctly decompressed), but the second one cause an error